# Does using sqlconnection.clearpool remove a single instance of a process from an app pool?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

If all connections with identical sql connection strings are dropped regardless of the individual instance calling the clearpool method, this sounds like a difficulty to me. We have an issue where the close and dispose methods of a sql connection don't actually clear it from the list of connections in the sql activity monitor, and we get a backlog of instances of this same stored procedure being called or active in some way. Based on this idea of all instances of the same process being cleared from the pool based on a single call from a single instance, it sounds as if any instance performing a sql transaction at the time it's being called would be dropped and cause an outage in the transaction that's occurring in mid-process.

A particular wrinkle in this for us is that several people are using our software product at the same time, and the sql connection strings referenced in the vb code are set up using the same variable name for everyone-- but that doesn't mean that all the actual strings assigned to the variable at runtime are the same, does it?

Is the backup of calls to the same procedure something that would be fully cleared from the queue using the .clearpool method, or would only the single instance be cleared? If the single instance is cleared, that's great.

I'm planning to test the sqlconnection.state to see if it's performing an action before using .clearpool to be sure it doesn't drop the connection while the stored procedure is running.

Answer (score 0):

Many misconceptions here.

> regardless of the individual instance calling the clearpool method

You cannot call this method on any instance. It is static. C# allows you to write it like an instance call but really it is not.

> We have an issue where the close and dispose methods of a sql connection don't actually clear it from the list of connections in the sql activity monitor

That is the whole purpose of pooling. The physical connection stays alive. All settings made on the logical connection are reset, through.

> and we get a backlog of instances of this same stored procedure being called or active in some way

Highly unlikely. When a connection is recycled it is reset. All transactions are rolled back. When you close a connection all running statements are killed. Note, though, that the reset happens when the connection is taken. Not when it is put back. For that reason you should explicitly rollback transactions that you do not wish to commit. Do this simply by disposing the reader and transaction objects.

> it sounds as if any instance performing a sql transaction at the time it's being called would be dropped and cause an outage in the transaction that's occurring in mid-process.

Clearing the pool only affects connections that are not in use. This is transparent to you.

> the sql connection strings referenced in the vb code are set up using the same variable name for everyone-- but that doesn't mean that all the actual strings assigned to the variable at runtime are the same, does it?

Why wouldn't it? Not enough information here to see any reason why.

> Is the backup of calls to the same procedure something that would be fully cleared from the queue using the .clearpool method, or would only the single instance be cleared?

This statement is based on false assumptions. Clearing the pool has no effect on connections that are in use. That would be a horrible design choice.

**Never clear the pool. Simply dispose of your connections when you no longer need them.**

Comment: There's plenty of advice here-- thank you for your help and clarifications. It's just odd that we declare a new sql connection, use it, close and dispose it and we're still seeing references to the closed processes in the processes tab of sql's activity monitor. If we recycle the app pool this clears up the lockups we're seeing and the users can go on, but we need to make it unnecessary, so that the project doesn't lock due to the long list of references we're seeing. Recycling the app pool seems to remove the processes from activity monitor. I'll post another comment to continue this.

Comment: Continued as promised: This application that's locking is a centrally hosted web application used by several endpoint users at workstations on a local area network. The front end code pages are vb with asp.net input form layers.

Comment: You either leak connections or you have the rollback issue that I talked about. If you simply close a connection with an open tran the rollback is delayed until the connection is reused. How is it possible, in your mind, that monitoring shows active sessions although you have properly ended all transactions and closed all connections? It is impossible. Maybe you are even misinterpreting the monitoring output.

Comment: I suppose it is impossible that the activity monitor shows anything that has been closed. Is that the case, that all monitoring shows is running processes? Could the processes I'm seeing be orphaned from their sessions due to simultaneous write actions being attempted on tables that are shared among the users calling these procedures? Could that lock or delay action to the system to a significant degree? Can the run state of a centrally accessible stored procedure be detected in a test before a call to it by one of the users is executed?

Comment: There is no run state for a procedure. It is pretty much just a blob of T-SQL. It can be run by any number of sessions concurrently. Locks and writes do not affect sessions and connections in any way. Execute sp_who2 to get an alternate view of what is running. Also, try sys.dm*tran_locks. I forgot the exact name. If you need more info than that that would be a new question. Not my specialty.

Comment: Thank you again. Truly, very much appreciated.